# How do we Get keyboard idle time in delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2, pascal

The following code can get the system idle time.

```
function IdleTime: DWord;
var
  LastInput: TLastInputInfo;
begin
  LastInput.cbSize := SizeOf(TLastInputInfo);
  GetLastInputInfo(LastInput);
  Result := (GetTickCount - LastInput.dwTime) DIV 1000;
end;
```

Is it possible to get keyboard idle time alone? Let the user move his/her mouse-it doesn't matter. Is it possible to determine, how long the keyboard has been idle?

Comment: Create a keyboard hook and keep your own timer going

Comment: Keyboard hook sounds like a key-logger. So i prefer to go with some other alternatives!

Comment: Well same concept no matter what it's being used for.

Comment: The OS does not provide the info you are looking for, so you have to hook the keyboard manually.

Comment: Maybe the [CallNtPowerInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372675%28VS.85%29.aspx) can be of any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to hook to Keyboard event. Check the Keyboard or mouse hooking in Delphi at

http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/a/delphi_hook.htm

and

http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-hooks.htm

You can build your logic over this.